# Is MariaDB 10.0 series compatible with PHP 5.6.10?

Tags: php, mariadb, vbulletin

Currently I am using MariaDB version 5.5.45 on CentOS 5.11 x86_64. Currently site has PHP version 5.3.29 and my forum site on this same server uses PHP version 5.6.10. My forum site is built using vBulletin version 4.2.3. So, I want to know whether it is safe to upgrade MariaDB 5.5 to 10.0 series? And is MariaDB 10.0 stable version compatible with vBulletin 4.2.3 and PHP 5.6?

I have tried a lot to get information about it on MariaDB official site and vBulletin but can't get sufficient and reliable information. It would be great if anyone can help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rick. 
From vBulletin support, I came to know that vBulletin 4.2.3 is compatible with MraiaDB 10+ series. However, vBulletin 4 does not have official support to MariaDB 10+. VB 5 has offical support to it.

Also, I have upgraded to MariaDB 10.0.21 and it is working fine without any problem with my vBulletin 4.2.3 and PHP 5.6.10 and also on site having PHP 5.3.29. There is only one change I have to do for this is, I have to change database user's old passwords to new ones before upgrading as MariaDB 10 uses different scheme to save database user's passwords. 
I think this information can be helpful to others.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect them to be compatible, with one exception...  Do *not* use the `mysql_*` interface in PHP.  Only use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  Your homework is to see what interface vBulletin uses.  (Glance at the code, if possible.)

Comment: I have upgraded to MariaDB 10+ and it is also working with mysql_* interface in PHP.